# Redirecting in HTACCESS from Query String to URL

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a URL with a query string to a URL without a query string, however, I would like to use values from the query string.

In my example below I am using a single state however I want it to be dynamic, meaning it will parse any URL with a query string down to a clean URL which still contains the value from the query string.

```
Example: http://www.mywebsite.com/?state=CA redirects to http://www.mywebsite.com/CA/
```

I have tired to add the information below into my HTACCESS file with no luck:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?state=([a-z]+)&type=([a-z\-]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?state=([a-z]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L]
```

These have worked however I must input every redirect which I would like to avoid:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=FL
RewriteRule ^$ "http://www.mywebsite.com/fl/?" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=RI
RewriteRule ^$ "http://www.mywebsite.com/ri/?" [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas? I am using WordPress on Apache. I believe everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the original rules won't work is because it seems like your state is:

```
state=FL
```

The `FL` will never match the regular expression `[a-z]+`, because `[a-z]` means literally any lowercase letter, and neither F nor L are lowercase. Try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?state=([a-z]+)&type=([a-z\-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?state=([a-z]+)($|\ ) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

So the `[NC]` flag in the condition makes it so the regular expression is case insensitive.

Comment: I am receiving a 500 error when using that code. The code below is also in my htaccess file because it is WordPress. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: @JonPotts they need to go before your wordpress rules, also, you need to add a `R=301` flag in the rules (see edit)

Comment: Would I be able to make it work for values with a space in between? Possibly a - or another symbol? Say I wanted to spell New York out rather than NY in the value. With the current code it will not work but I would like it to redirect to website.com/new-york/ if possible.

Comment: @JonPotts You can replace the `([a-z]+)` to something more general like `([^&\ ]+)` to match anything that's not the end of the parameter.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough Jon Lin. After hours and hours of tinkering with this it finally works within minutes of your help. I appreciate your time and thought.

Comment: @JonPotts you should click on the green check-mark so that the question is marked as resolved.