# redirect urls from query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect urls from query string using this code:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

This worked well for:
       www.example.com/mypage.html?gclid=xxx

But it does not work for:

```
    www.example.com/?gclid=xxx

    www.example.com/mypage.html/?gclid=xxx
```

Also tried unsuccessfully [1]:this answer [question]:[Redirecting in HTACCESS from Query String to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103717/redirecting-in-htaccess-from-query-string-to-url)

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?gclid=([a-z]+)&type=([a-z\-]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?gclid=([a-z]+)($|\ ) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

What changes could I do?

thank you very much

Comment: I notice you are testing with permanent redirects, and you might have cached an old invalid redirect test in your browser. Clear your browser cache and test if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I would expect the first rule in your question to work properly, except for a request to the site root (`http://www.example.com/`). This is because `(.+)` must be at least 1 character, and a request to the site root is an empty string there. For all other pages it would work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect site root url all others is ok with the first rule. Tried now without        (.+) but dont work

Comment: Just change `.+` with `.*` then.

Comment: Bingo,         .* worked! Thank you. how to mark as resolved?